# Laravel Inheritance Fail

Tags: php, oauth, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4 and I have this code here:

http://demo.php-pastebin.com/2sfuOUE7

Above the first line there is a line where I include another class file (CHPPConnection, which is a library for easier implement of OAuth 1.0, located at http://pht.htloto.org)

This is the code for the retrieveAccessToken method in that library:

```
/**
 * Get access token for chpp application
 *
 * @param String $oauthToken
 * @param String $verifier
 */
public function retrieveAccessToken($oauthToken, $verifier)
{
    $params = array(
        'oauth_consumer_key' => $this->consumerKey,
        'oauth_signature_method' => $this->signatureMethod,
        'oauth_timestamp' => $this->getTimestamp(),
        'oauth_nonce' => $this->getNonce(),
        'oauth_token' => $oauthToken,
        'oauth_verifier' => $verifier,
        'oauth_version' => $this->version
    );
    $signature = $this->buildSignature(self::OAUTH_SERVER.self::ACCESS_URL, $params, $this->oauthFirstTokenSecret);
    $params['oauth_signature'] = $signature;
    uksort($params, 'strcmp');
    $url = $this->buildOauthUrl(self::OAUTH_SERVER.self::ACCESS_URL, $params);
    if($this->canLog())
    {
        $this->log("[OAUTH] Access url: ".$url);
    }
    $return = $this->fetchUrl($url, false);
    $result = explode('&', $return);
    foreach($result as $val)
    {
        $t = explode('=', $val);
        $$t[0] = urldecode($t[1]);
    }
    if(isset($oauth_token))
    {
        $this->setOauthToken($oauth_token);
        if($this->canLog())
        {
            $this->log("[OAUTH] Access token: ".$oauth_token);
        }
    }
    if(isset($oauth_token_secret))
    {
        $this->setOauthTokenSecret($oauth_token_secret);
        if($this->canLog())
        {
            $this->log("[OAUTH] Access token secret: ".$oauth_token_secret);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is my code not working? Why the **__constructor** method returns results I want, but the **something** method doesn't? I probably have some wrong understanding how inheritance works in this case, so please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's maybe because you are trying to return something in your constructor, so maybe when you instantiate it, you aren't retrieving an instance of it but an instance of pht, which obviously wouldn't have the `something()` function you are looking for.

```
class PhtController extends BaseController {

    protected $_pht;

    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->_pht = new CHPPConnection(
                            Config::get("pht.consumerKey"),
                            Config::get("pht.consumerSecret"),
                            Config::get("pht.callback"));
            //this returns true
    }

    public function something()
    {
            $at = $this->_pht->retrieveAccessToken($_REQUEST["oauth_token"], $_REQUEST["oauth_verifier"]);

           //vardump $at here dumps just NULL and cannot use any other methods aswell, returns false
    }
}

// If you need to retrieve the instance of pht for any reason, call this function rather than returning it in the constructor.
public function getPHT()
{
    return $this->_pht;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Unfortunately that did not help.